# Data not coming up in datagridview, predefined columns in datagrid now mapping cells to datatable values

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

in datatable there are 4 rows coming and that i have to pull in datagridview using for loop, so whats happening is only last row is coming in datagrid out of 4 from datatable take a look

there is 4 rows in datatble "DTItems"

```
If DTItems.Rows.Count > 0 Then
For i As Integer = 0 To DTItems.Rows.Count - 1
If DataGridViewItems.Rows.Count <= i Then DataGridViewItems.Rows.Add()
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(1)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(2)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(3)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(4)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(5)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(6)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(7)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(8)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(9)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(10)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(11)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(12)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(13)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(14)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(0)
DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value = 0
Next
End If
```

i am getting 3 blank rows in datagrid views and 4th one is coming.

Comment: Can you show the datagrid code and what do you mean with the 4th one is coming?

Comment: `i have to pull in datagridview using for loop` No you dont.  You could bind the DataTable to the DGV.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the line:

```
If DataGridViewItems.Rows.Count <= i Then DataGridViewItems.Rows.Add()
```

The `<=` means less than or equal to so you are only adding a row when `i` reaches `DataGridViewItems.Rows.Count`

Try changing it to:

```
If DataGridViewItems.Rows.Count >= i Then DataGridViewItems.Rows.Add()
```

Also you are trying to add data regardless of whether you are adding the row, updating the data should probably also be inside the `If DataGridViewItems.Rows.Count >= i Then` or to be tidier simply end the loop when `i` is greater than the number of rows.

Such as:

```
If DTItems.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To DTItems.Rows.Count - 1
        If DataGridViewItems.Rows.Count > i Then Exit For
        DataGridViewItems.Rows.Add() 
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(1)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(2)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(3)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(4)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(5)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(6)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(7)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(8)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(9)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(10)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(11)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(12)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(13)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(13).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(14)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value = DTItems.Rows(i).Item(0)
        DataGridViewItems.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value = 0
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue was resolved, actually the default property of datagridview of allow user to add row was set to true, so i have changed it to false and it started working .